# Amazon Product Advertising API - Class 'AwsV4' not found

Tags: php, sdk, amazon-product-api

I am trying to use the Amazon Product Advertising API and I use the class `AwsV4` to sign my request.

I get the message: `Uncaught Error: Class 'AwsV4' not found` although I have included the libraries.

I have followed the instructions from [Installing the AWS SDK for PHP Version 3 - AWS SDK for PHP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/getting-started_installation.html) in section *Installing by using the ZIP file*.

I downloaded the zip, extracted in and included the file that says in the guide. `require '/path/to/aws-autoloader.php'`

Anybody knows something? Should I include something else that is not mentioned? I am on windows, PHP 7.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Rain were you able to fetch the products?